# How to also toogle a div outside a Bootstrap accordion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap accordion and I love the way it works in [this example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse). However, I'd like to be able to toggle an additional section outside that accordion.

Is there a quick trick or should I try to develop my own widget?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the bootstrap accordion, but you could add some simple jQuery:

```
$(".accordion-toggle").on(click, function() {
  $(".other-section").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to bootstrap event hooks

"Bootstrap's collapse class exposes a few events for hooking into collapse functionality."

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

Check doc here:  [twitter bootstrap collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)